# Why does this pointer contain an address stored on the heap?

Tags: c++, pointers, c-strings

Here is my code (`g++` compiler on Mac OS):

```
/* initialize character arrays */
char a[2] = "a";
char b[2] = "b";

/* assigns to c the pointer to a read-only buffer containing 'c' */
char* c = "c"; // does this cause a memory leak?

/* allocate heap-memory for d */
char* d = new char[2];
strcpy(d, "d");

/* print addresses and values */
std::cout << (void*)a << ":" << a << '\n';
std::cout << (void*)b << ":" << b << '\n';
std::cout << (void*)c << ":" << c << '\n';
std::cout << (void*)d << ":" << d << '\n';

/* free memory */
delete d[];
```

Before seeing the output of this program, I would have expected `a`, `b`, and `c` to contain addresses on the stack, and `d` an address on the heap. However, the output looks something like this:

```
0x7fff5a5ea38e:a
0x7fff5a5ea38c:b
0x105616f7c:c
0x7fa01bc02690:d
```

Since the stack pointer grows down from the highest address, and the heap pointer up from the lowest address, it seems that `a`, `b`, and `d` are stored on the stack, while `c` is stored on the heap. Is this the case?

My question is, why would it make sense that `c` is stored on the heap, since I did not allocate memory with the `new` keyword? Does this mean that initialization of `c` has created a memory-leak? Why is `d` stored on the stack, since I specifically allocated memory on the heap?

Thanks!

Comment: You called `new` without calling `delete`, so yes, you have a memory leak.

Comment: @juanchopanza Sorry, I am referring to the code used to initialize `c`.

Comment: The C++ standard makes no mention of heap or stack or where they grow. So it's not like this isn't an allowed set of addresses

Comment: `c` is a string literal. It is likely stored in a read-only section that would be separate from anything else. But, that's still just an assumption that will be platform specific. In any case, it does not cause a memory leak.

Comment: @RetiredNinja The argument that `c` is stored in a read-only section of memory because it's a string literal would not explain the behavior seen for the remaining three variables, since they *all* are initialized with string literals.

Comment: Initialized with a string literal is not the same as pointer to a string literal. All of your other variables are pointers to allocated memory that you copy the contents of a string literal into. For fun, try modifying a character in each. a, b, d will work, c probably will not.

Comment: What you're asking involves things that may vary from compiler to compiler, and from machine to machine. It would be good if you could add to your question what compiler you're using and on what OS you're running.

Comment: It's `delete[] d;`, not `delete d[];`.

Answer (score 4):

Your guesses about memory regions are not very accurate.  `a` and `b` do live on the stack, since they are arrays.  However, `c` is a pointer to a string literal, which is stored in a `.rodata` section in the binary image (which is neither stack nor heap).  `d`'s value is 380 GB(!) smaller than `a` and `b`; it is on the heap (which is a separate memory area, though not at any kind of "lowest address").

Bear in mind that, in addition to being a platform-specific detail irrelevant to the language, things like [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) make this sort of spectator sport difficult.

Comment: It's worth noting that while everything you've said is correct on some platforms, there is no guarantee in any standard that any platform will behave this way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! How is initialization of c-style arrays handled in the case of string literals? Why is it not the case that `a` contains the address of the first character stored in the `.rodata` section?

Comment: @yonatano In your example `a` is a pointer to 2 bytes of modifiable memory that contains `{'a', '\0'}`. How those contents got there is up to the compiler. It's almost certain there is no actual string literal stored anywhere, certainly not something you could get the actual address of.

Comment: @RetiredNinja: `a` is not a pointer at all, but an array of exactly those two bytes.

Comment: @DavisHerring You're right, I have too many pointers on the brain. :)